# How to replace union by join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, union

```
select service_type from service_type as s union select service_type
from cust_service_type as cs
```

I want to replace `UNION` by `JOINS`. Please let me know the changes that will need to be made.

Comment: They are not equivalent.  To use `JOIN`, there would have to be some relationship between the tables, such as a `service_id`.

Comment: What's bad in a `UNION`?

Comment: Both table are same in structure and i want all data from first table and from second table i want that data which is not match from first table.

Answer (score 2):

`MySQL` does not support `FULL JOIN` so it's impossible to do this in `MySQL`.

In other systems, you could use this syntax:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT COALESCE(service_type, cust_service_type)
FROM    service_type s
FULL JOIN
        cust_service_type cs
ON      cs.service_type = s.service_type
```

or

```
SELECT  DISTINCT service_type
FROM    service_type s
FULL JOIN
        cust_service_type cs
USING   (service_type)
```

for systems that support `JOIN ... USING`

Note that `UNION` is much more efficient than this solution.

**Update:**

If you want all fields from both tables, use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    service_type s
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    cust_service_type cs
WHERE   service_type NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  service_type
        FROM    service_type
        )
```